# Vuforia Failed to Initialize on Android L?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am trying to figure out how to develop Vuforia 5.5.9 using Unity. I made a test project which works with my laptop's webcam, but when I try to put it on a phone, which is running Android 5.1.1 Lollipop, I get a grey screen which says "Vuforia Initialization Error" and "Failed to Initialize Vuforia", and at the bottom there's a "Close" button. This seems like the [same error people get when they run into Android M permission issues](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/device-support/android-m-vuforia-initializing-failed), but I don't have Android M involved anywhere in my build. I am using the Android sdk version 22 (lollipop), have minSdkVersion="19" and targetSdkVersion="22" in my manifest, and, as mentioned before, am running 5.1.1 on the phone.

How can I get more information about what's going wrong? I'm new to Vuforia and Unity development so I don't know how to get more detailed information about the failure (or if that sort of information is even available). All I know is that it's giving me the "Failed to initialize Vuforia" error, and whenever I google that error I ONLY get results about the Android M permissions bug, which can't be affecting me.

Edit: I am using a Samsung Note 4. I looked at logcat and this is the output I get:

```
E/Unity   (27638): Unable to find libaudioplugingvrunity
D/Unity   (27638):  GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_framebuffer_object GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr GL_OES_texture_npot GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_OES_texture_3D GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_QCOM_alpha_testGL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_EXT_sRGB GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_texture_half_floatGL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_EXT_copy_image GL_EXT_geometry_shader GL_EXT_tessellation_shaderGL_OES_texture_stencil8 GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks GL_OES_shader_image_atomic GL_OES_sample_variables GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_OES_shader_multisample_interpolation GL_EXT_texture_cube_map_array GL_EXT_d
D/Unity   (27638): raw_buffers_indexed GL_EXT_gpu_shader5 GL_EXT_robustness GL_EXT_texture_buffer GL_OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array GL_OES_sample_shading GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_EXT_debug_labelGL_KHR_blend_equation_advancedGL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering GL_ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a GL_EXT_primitive_bounding_box GL_OES_standard_derivativesGL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query GL_KHR_debug GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control
I/Unity   (27638): Setting BehaviourComponentFactory
I/Unity   (27638):
I/Unity   (27638): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)
I/Unity   (27638):
I/Unity   (27638): Trackable target lost
I/Unity   (27638):
I/Unity   (27638): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)
I/Unity   (27638):
E/Unity   (27638): Vuforia initialization failed
E/Unity   (27638):
E/Unity   (27638): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)
E/Unity   (27638):
E/Unity   (27638): Vuforia initialization failed:
E/Unity   (27638):
E/Unity   (27638): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)
E/Unity   (27638):
```

Comment: 1. What device are you testing on. 2. Anything in the logcat which can help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Samsung note 4. I am only learning about logcat now, so I'm going to take a look at that

Comment: @MorrisonChang I added the output from the logcat -- it looks helpful to me, but I don't know enough to really make sense of it. I'm going to try googling a bunch of the stuff in the logcat.

Comment: `Unable to find libaudioplugingvrunity` is a start. Perhaps you are doing something different with audio. I would also check the plugin/SDK version and make sure your version of Unity is supported. Note even though you only have 5.x - the plugin may require higher, but as long as you've got the minimum you should try to see if the default config works for you.

Comment: I'm not doing anything with audio (not even doing anything with GVR I'm pretty sure), so according to this: https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/239 I should be able to ignore that error since I'm not using GVR audio.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of unity (5.3.5) and this page: https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Solution/Vuforia-Supported-Versions says that Vuforia should support everything past 5.2.4

Comment: Do you have a license key in the Vuforia Camera component?

Comment: yes, I do. I figured out the problem I was having, actually -- I'm pretty sure it was happening because I had the orientation set to Auto instead of Landscape Left. I'll post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

My problem went away when I made a new project. One thing that I did with the new project but not the previous one was that I set the orientation to Landscape Left (instead of Auto).

Another thing that may have to do with this is think I might have installed a ton of random packages in the previous project, including maybe Google VR, and that might have interfered.

Comment: Yes ton of random packages can cause problem. I have the same error when I am using unity to build AR app in android ' actually I have created a android plugin and changed the android manifest file and forgot to add permission for camera usage as unity merge your created manifest file with original manifest that created the conflict, adding permission solve my problem.